# Show Gif on click and Hide after Ajax Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found lots os posts with the solution to my problem, but no one works to me...

I tried like:

```
<div class="ibox-content">                     

    <div id="carregando" class="text-center" style="display:none">
    <img src="~/Imagens/logo.png" />
    </div>

    <div id="container" style="height: 460px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</div>
```

My JS is called on a button clink who calls a funcion like bellow:

```
$("#atualiza").click(function () {           

    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#carregando").show();
    });

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Portaria/AtendOperador',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'data1': data1, 'data2': data2, 'evento': evento, 'cuc': cuc, 'conta': conta },
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            delay: 15,
            success: function (data) {

                var Categories = new Array();
                var Series = new Array();

                for (var i in data) {
                    Categories.push(data[i].Operador);
                    Series.push(data[i].Fechados);
                }

                var CategArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Categories));
                atendOperador(CategArray, Series);


                $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                    $("#carregando").hide();
                });
            },



            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('error');

                $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                    $("#carregando").hide();
                });

            }
        });      
});


function atendOperador(CategArray, Series) {

    var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        }   

    });
}
```

Even I put the code:

```
 $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
     $( "#carregando" ).show();
 });
```

The image appear only after ajax finishing. Using the two blocks, show and Hide, the image not appear, so, i tried to remove the hide block and i could see that the problem is: Show and Hide happens together when ajax is loaded like:

I cliked on button and noting happened like: http://prntscr.com/ars97n

And after few seconds, Ajax load data and show icon and data together: http://prntscr.com/ars9xq

Comment: I dont know why, but if i replace the blocks AjaxStart and AjaxStop for alert('start'); and alert('stop') the warnings appear on correctly.

Comment: I created a fiddle and my solution works as expected for the error state. I'm assuming it would work for success to. https://jsfiddle.net/aboachjn/ then click atualiza in the bottom right square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! I found the problem here! All ways I tried before works now, with this modification I did.

Just:

```
 $("#carregando").show();
```

Or:

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#carregando").show();
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $("#carregando").hide();
    });
```

Or:

```
 beforeSend: function() {
                $("#carregando").show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $("#carregando").hide();
            },
```

All my problem were here: http://prntscr.com/asbxbk!!!

So, I commented that **async** and works!!!

```
  $("#atualiza").click(function () {

    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#carregando").show();
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $("#carregando").hide();
    });           

        $.ajax({    
            url: '/Portaria/AtendOperador',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'data1': data1, 'data2': data2, 'evento': evento, 'cuc': cuc, 'conta': conta },

            //async: false, COMMENTED!!!           

            success: function (data) {    
                var Categories = new Array();
                var Series = new Array();    
                for (var i in data) {
                    Categories.push(data[i].Operador);
                    Series.push(data[i].Fechados);
                }    
                var CategArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Categories));
                atendOperador(CategArray, Series);
            },    
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('error');
            }
        }); 
});
```

Comment: Karl, you fiddle helped me to find the way to explain my real problem... In your example, its seems to work by the alert on error. If you comment your alert, the start call, and the stop call will happen at the same time, and the image will be not showed.

Comment: Makes sense if your ajax call happens very quickly.

Comment: Even Ajax make long time to load the Data, i dont know why but the show calling, always happen togther with load data, but, if i put the Alerts or debugger on the navigator it works. Too newbie to understand :( :(

Answer (score 2):

Try `$("#carregando").hide();` instead of `$(document).ajaxStop(function ()$("#carregando").hide();});`

edit: ajaxStart and ajaxEnd are event handlers. I think they should be registered *outside* of the click function. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#carregando").show();
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $("#carregando").hide();
    });
    $("#atualiza").click(function () { 
        /* all your code here except for the ajaxStart/ajaxStop portion */
    });
});
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer Karl... First of all, i tried:   $("#carregando").hide();
    $("#carregando").show(); but gave me the same result. I cant understand, but if i put an alert istead, the alerts works as i desire, appearing when i click first alert, and after when the data is loaded.

Comment: @RogerioAzevedo I created a fiddle and my solution works as expected for the error state. I'm assuming it would work for success to. https://jsfiddle.net/aboachjn/ then click atualiza in the bottom right square

Answer (score 1):

As Karl stated, the best way to do it is without using `ajaxStart/ajaxStop` event handlers, or even better, without using jQuery at all.

```js
document.querySelector('.get-data').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.display-data').textContent = null;
  document.querySelector('.loading').style.display = 'block';

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos', true);

  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      // Success!
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      document.querySelector('.loading').style.display = 'none';
      document.querySelector('.display-data').textContent = JSON.stringify(data[0]);
    } else {
      // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
      document.querySelector('.loading').style.display = 'none';
    }
  };

  request.onerror = function() {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
    document.querySelector('.loading').style.display = 'none';
  };

  request.send();
});
```

```html
<button class="get-data">Get Data</button>
<div class="loading" style="display: none">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif" width="50px">
</div>
<div class="display-data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Karl's answer is correct if you want to show the same git for all ajax request on the page

But if you want to do it for this particular AJAX the follow this

```
$("#atualiza").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() { $("#carregando").show(); }, //It will show the gif just before sending the request
            url: '/Portaria/AtendOperador',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'data1': data1, 'data2': data2, 'evento': evento, 'cuc': cuc, 'conta': conta },
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            delay: 15,
            success: function (data) {

                var Categories = new Array();
                var Series = new Array();

                for (var i in data) {
                    Categories.push(data[i].Operador);
                    Series.push(data[i].Fechados);
                }

                var CategArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Categories));
                atendOperador(CategArray, Series);
                $("#carregando").hide();   //this will hide the gif in case of AJAX success
            },



            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('error');
                $("#carregando").hide();   //this will hide the gif in case of AJAX failure
            }
        });      
});
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Karl and Cybersupernova, I tried your sugests and it gave me same problem. I left the hide block comented to check this out and I could see the gif only after data is loaded. Something strange is, if i put debbugers it works, step by step. Someone told me abou a jquery library to do that, Jquery load mask, do you know that?

Comment: Tried with a jquery component and it gave me the same problem, the gif, aways apear together of the data load. Maybe, the problem é my JS, the way how i did that, maybe something about asynchronous AJAX

Comment: AJAX are asynchronous requests you can not debug it correctly using debuggers use debugger just inside the success function only then you can see actually whats happening